# Defining a class with or without the .prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype, factory, object-create

In the absence of using the `class` keyword, what is the difference between the following two ways to construct an inherited object? In the first one I'm attaching things on the `.prototype` and in the second one I'm doing it directly on the function. What would be the difference?

```js
function basicPrototype(){};
basicPrototype.prototype.sayHi = function(name){
    console.log("Hello,", name);
}

function basicConstructor() {
    return this; // make sure to pass it a this
}

let basicObj = basicConstructor.call(Object.create(basicPrototype.prototype));
basicObj.sayHi("Tommy");
```

And removing the `.prototype` on the two lines?

```js
function basicPrototype(){};
basicPrototype.sayHi = function(name){
    console.log("Hello,", name);
}

function basicConstructor() {
    return this; // make sure to pass it a this
}

let basicObj = basicConstructor.call(Object.create(basicPrototype));
basicObj.sayHi("Tommy");
```

Comment: In the first example the invocation of `basicConstructor.call` is not needed, for everything needed already gets done by `Object.create(basicPrototype.prototype)` all alone, just try it ... `let basicObj = Object.create(basicPrototype.prototype); basicObj.sayHi("Tommy");` ... already is perfectly fine. Doing it with `basicConstructor.call` is just like passing `basicObj` to it ... `basicConstructor.call(basicObj)` ... and nothing happens since the delegated `basicObj` gets not mutated, just returned by what the OP calls `basicConstructor`. The latter and calling it it just totally unnecessary.

Comment: The same applies to the second example code ... `let basicObj = Object.create(basicPrototype);` ... is everything needed. Thus, the real question is ... _"What is the difference in between the object creation of `Object.create(basicPrototype.prototype)` and. `Object.create(basicPrototype)`?"_

Comment: @PeterSeliger I see, thanks for clarifying. Would you want to write an answer combining your two comments plus the `.prototype` thing?

Comment: Answer hereby provided.

Comment: I had to rework/correct/improve my answer since I overlooked a minor but important implementation detail of your second example's code. In an interview question I would have failed.

Comment: As final conclusion one could state. The example code is a tricky brainteaser where at no point anything class related (in terms of constructor functions and constructor function prototypes) is involved. Everything gets achieved by the class/constructor less alternative of `Object.create`. The rest is just tricky, harmless obfuscation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code of both examples can be cleaned up since `basicConstructor.call` does not have any effect to the passed object which shortly before was created via `Object.reate`.

In addition `basicConstructor` despite its name is not a constructor at all since it never creates instances due to never being invoked with `new`. (It also does not feature any implementations neither within the function body nor own prototypal ones.) Thus `basicConstructor` acts more like a (identity?) function/method which returns the reference of its call time's `this` context. So it's dispensable.

From the above comments ...

> Thus, the real question is ... *"What is the difference in between the object creation of `Object.create(basicPrototype.prototype)` and `Object.create(basicPrototype)`?"*

Well it is pretty obvious that the former creates a new object with `basicPrototype.prototype` set as the new object's prototype, the latter creates an object which has the function `basicPrototype` set as the new object's prototype ...

... which means that calling/sending `sayHi` on/to `basicObj` for both cases technically is the same. Since `basicObj` has not such an own property there will be lookups into both object's prototype chains.

And both methods are found immediately since both prototypes feature `sayHi` as their own property which is clear for the former case but (for some) maybe surprising for the latter case. (I had to look at it twice/three times myself and countercheck again.) The second example does implement and assign `sayHi` as direct property to the function `basicPrototype`. Thus for the latter case the function mainly acts as a dump object like `basicPrototype.prototype` does for the former case.

As final conclusion one could state. The example code is a tricky brainteaser where at no point anything class related (in terms of constructor functions and constructor function prototypes) is involved. Everything gets achieved by the class/constructor less alternative of `Object.create`. The rest is just tricky, harmless obfuscation.